# Key detection problem in JavaScript. What is wrong with my function?

Tags: javascript, keyboard

So I want to create a basic RPG (with extremely bad graphics) and the following code for detecting the up arrow key doesn't work... Any suggestions? (note that I'm a n00bie)

```
document.onkeydown = event => {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";

    if (event.key == (keyCode == '38')) {
        height -= 25;
        ctx.clear();
        ctx.fillRect(width, height, 25, 50);
    }
```

I'm gonna send the fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/xedra6bn/
As you can see I haven't done the other arrow keys so don't try them as a test.

Comment: Actually, there is an error regarding your ctx.Clear() function. It is not created, and because of that, console is showing an error, and your function cannot be executed.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was how you clear the canvas...  I really am a n00b! 

Comment: No problem, there is actually something similar to what you wanted to do, I've posted it in the answer.

Comment: Makes more sense...  sorry for wasting your time like that. Should've went to w3schools...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you have not created a Clear function, and your console is showing an error, and your if statement should be a little bit different. So:

```
document.onkeydown = event => {
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";

    if (event.keyCode == '38')//change your if statemment like this {
        height -= 25;
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.fillRect(width, height, 25, 50);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Check the key code like this:

```js
if (event.keyCode === 38) {
    // some code
}
```

**EDIT**

`keyCode` is deprecated. You can use `key`:

```js
if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
    // some code
}
```

Comment: it seems like it doesn't work. It marks it as "deprecated" on VScode. Has it got something to do with the clear() function?

Comment: something wrong with the clear() function on js fiddle. What do I do now?!

Comment: Oh, right. That's deprecated. Well, then you can use `event.code` or `event.key`. Note that they return a string. I edited the answer